# Washing machine waste pipe

Tags: washing-machine

- Location: West Bengal India.
- Electrical supply: 240V AC.
- Model: IFB TL-SDR 6.5 Kg Aqua.

Question: Should I install a stand pipe for waste water draining for now, or later, if the washing machine model is changed?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: According to the instructions it doesn’t need a stand pipe , I have never seen a washer That did not need a stand pipe.

Comment: @EdBeal  We have to live with inspectors, and most of them will not allow us to run the drain pipe out the door either.  Would probably be good for the septic tank not to have all those soap suds in it.

Comment: @crip659 maybe you missed it this op is not in the US and the manufacturer shows a 10cm height limit and the hose end can not be submerged so this may be a gravity drain system, as my comment shows I read both the question and the photos of the instructions. Note many areas in the US do allow for gray water drainage without a septic system but require a dry well or drain field no tank.and as I stated I have never seen a system like this as the stand pipe holds the water in a standard US washer and the pump pushes the water out

Comment: Many thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the instructions you provided, and as noted in a comment, no, you don't appear to need a drain pipe for *your* washer. That seems to address the factual portion of your question.

---

As to *should* you, well, that's a matter of opinion. Opinion based questions are off-topic here because there's no practical way we can answer for you. However, I believe I can give you a general guideline to help *you* make your determination.

1. Are you expecting to change the washer soon, potentially to a model that will require a drain pipe?
2. Are you doing other work on the house where adding a drain pipe now would be a reasonable and simple extra step?

- If the answer to both is 'Yes', it seems like adding the drain pipe would be a reasonable thing to do.
- If the answer to 2 is 'yes', you may want to do the install even if 1 is 'no' because "while we're at it...".
- If the answer to both is 'no', then this seems to be an unnecessary extra step.

  - I suppose if you've got an unusual model of washer (and for the US, not needing a drain pipe *is* unusual, I haven't a clue for Indian installations), and you own the place, and you're considering future resale value, and you're considering selling the place in the foreseeable future, then it might be beneficial to spend the money now, but only you can determine the cost/benefit of that decision.

---

In any case, be sure to install *this* washing machine according to *its* instructions.

Comment: If a gravity drain a stand pipe would allow the washer to fill and it could never drain that might be the reason for the 10cm or aprox 4” max height and the end not submerged so it can’t syphon the water back.

Comment: Many Thanks, for all the observations. I will think over points 1 and 2.

Comment: Good point, @EdBeal, I added a note at the bottom to address that